# Why does runOnUiThread work for me while Handler.post does not

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, android-runonuithread

I have a `Fragment` that contains a `RecyclerView`. Within that `Fragment`, I load some data from a database, populate the `RecyclerView` with it and then want to scroll to a certain position in that `RecyclerView`.

To perform the scrolling on the UI thread after loading the data, I wanted to use a handler:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private mHandler Handler = new Handler();

    //....

    private void onDataAvailable() {
        // ...
        int scrollPosition = getScrollPosition();
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(scrollPosition);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

However, it never scrolls down.

When I use `runOnUiThread`, everything works:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    //....

    private void onDataAvailable() {
        // ...
        int scrollPosition = getScrollPosition();
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(scrollPosition);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

No matter if I instantiate `mHandler` as `new Handler()` or as `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())`, it doesn't work.

My understanding was that `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())` would allow me to execute tasks on the UI thread and should have the same effect as `runOnUiThread`. What's wrong in my thinking?

**UPDATE**

For test purposes, I am calling `onDataAvailable` from the end of my `onCreateView` function and with mock data loaded. Same effect: With my own handler, it fails to scroll. With runOnUiThread, it works perfectly.

Even more interestingly, I printed the thread ID from outside the runnable for both the handler and runOnUiThread. Both times, the code is run on Thread 1, no difference.

**UPDATE 2**

Everything works if I use `mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition` rather than `smoothScrollToPosition`. Any idea what that could be?

Comment: If you look at sources they are exceptionally same thing. `runOnUiThread` performs exact same thing with `Handler`. Not sure what may cause that.

Comment: use postDelayed it's work. i dont know why... but its work

mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(scrollPosition);
            }
        },1);

Comment: You should show when onDataAvailable is called. Handler always post to an event queue. runOnUiThread might execure immediately.

Comment: `postDelayed` doesn't make any difference. I'll add some information how onDataAvailable is called.

Comment: I have the same problem with runOnUiThread and Handler.post methods, but I execute very simple code - change view's visibility. And I don't know why runOnUiThread works and Handler.post doesn't work. Is there any explanations?